# My Compaq Presario would not come on

Tags: laptop-repair, compaq-laptop

My Compaq Presario cq60 does not come up at all when I try to put it on. But immediately I plug in a charger to it, the charging light shows white and the power light comes up to and so the fan like its on and nothing still comes up, when I even try to put it off with the power button, it doesn't work unless I unplug the charger,  its AMD processor.  Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're not the only one to have this problem.

[According to this thread here](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-502171-compaq-presario-cq60-won-t-turn-on), your model of laptop tends to have issues with RAM connection and the battery.

Try the following troubleshooting steps:
 - remove and clean the RAM using a soft cloth (do not use glass cleaner, alcohol or any harsh abrasive) 
 - remove the battery and try to boot the system while it is plugged in
- connect an external monitor to your system and power it on with the lid closed. It may be that the backlight element in your display died and the screen is actually on but without illumination it is too dark to see.

If the system boots after cleaning ram, you're good. If it boot without a battery, then buy a new battery. If it boots on an external display, then look up a PC repair shop and have them replace the backlight for you.